# openmp fortran code runs slower than serial code

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I am trying to apply openmp to parallize the following snippet as shown below. However, the paralleled code turns out to be running slower than serial one without the openmp derivatives. I am running on 64 linux platform and compile with gfortran. 
You comments and suggestions about how to do it properly are appreciated!

```
        call omp_set_num_threads(4)

    do i = 2, natoms - 1

          rti(1:3) = R_for(i,1:3)
          fti(1:3) = ftmp(i,1:3)

    !$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(SHARED)&
    !$OMP& private(rtij,rsqij,rsqijinv,sr2,sr6,sr12,vij,wij,fij,ftij,ncut)&
    !$OMP& REDUCTION(+:vtmp,wtmp,ftmp,fti) &
    !$OMP& firstprivate(i,rti,R_for)

    do j = i + 1, natoms
        rtij = rti - R_for(j,1:3)
        rtij = rtij - boxl*idnint( rtij*boxlinv )
        rsqij = sum(rtij**2)

                if(rsqij.lt.rcutsq) then
                   rsqijinv = 1d0/rsqij
                   sr2 = sigsq*rsqijinv
                   sr6 = sr2*sr2*sr2
                   sr12 = sr6*sr6
                   vij = sr12 - sr6
                   vtmp = vtmp + vij
                   wij = vij + sr12
                   wtmp = wtmp + wij
                   fij = wij*rsqijinv

                   ftij = fij*rtij
                   fti = fti + ftij
                   ftmp(j,1:3) = ftmp(j,1:3) - ftij(1:3)
                   ncut = ncut + 1
                endif
enddo
    !$OMP END PARALLEL DO

        ftmp(i,1:3) = fti(1:3) 
enddo
```

Comment: It costs to set up the "thread" for parallelisation, so if it ain't doing much or they are blocking to access a common resource, then it won't be faster, in fact it could be much slower. Tidy up your code, make it the parallel one, and some vague clues as to what its doing would be good.

Comment: I have removed the comments and tidy up the code. I am mostly wondering on two things: 1. whether there are unseen dependency in the paralleled loop that i do not spot. 2. any other way to improve it

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Tony Hopkinson, thread creation introduces some overhead, thus you should move the parallel region out of the outer loop and put the assignment of shared variables into a workshare or single construct.

Then, instead of the reduction clause you could use arrays with the length of the number of threads to store thread local partial sums and do the reduction only after the loop completed vtmp and wtmp for example seem nowhere to be used, and could be reduced even after the outer loop. Due to the if condition it looks like your loop might be heavily unbalanced from iteration to iteration, and it might be beneficial to use some dynamic scheduling.